# Access attributes on model from ActionContext in ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, actionfilterattribute

Given a custom *ActionFilterAttribute*, is there a way to access attributes on the action's model using the *HttpActionContext* within an overriden OnActionExecuting method?

I wish to throw an exception if attributes are not a particular type.

For example:

A custom attribute exists called `[CustomRequired]`. If there are any usages of `[Required]` on the model, then an exception is thrown. The model should have used `[CustomRequired]`, not `[Required]`

```
public class ModelValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        ValidateModelAttributes(actionContext);
    }

    private static void ValidateModelAttributes(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var attrs = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters();
        foreach (var attr in attrs) 
        {
             // if attr is not type then throw exception
        }
    }
}
```